# Cross referencing two texts

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Consider these statements

`Exercise 1. $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative.`

`Exercise 2. By Exercise 1 we have $\phi(n)=\prod_{p|n}(1-1/p)$.`

Suppose I want to cross refer Exercise 2 to Exercise 1 what command should I give??

I looked at various example on this site, but I am unable to understand anything. I tried

- `Exercise 1. \label{1} $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative`
- `Exercise 2. By \ref{1} we have ..... but this doesn't work.`

Kindly help.

Comment: To use the TeX/LaTeX `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing system, you generally need a counter variable that's incremented automatically (usually via a `\refstepcounter` directive). Please tell us how the `exercise` list is constructed and how the counter is incremented.

Comment: @Mico Em. Exercise list is constructed using the \textbf{Exercise 1 } command, there is no listing as such :(

Comment: If you set the number by hand, how is the computer program supposed to know that there even is a number to be referred to. You have to define an environment along with a suitable counter. And when labeling stuff, don't use numerical labels. It is the worst you can do. Do something like `label{multiplicativePhi}`.

Comment: I looked at your profile, you are a member for four years and have asked 23 questions. Why don't you use proper marup for your questions and comments?

Comment: @Johannes_B Sorry. I am not used to it

Comment: Use the `xr` package

Comment: @Mico: Not if `two texts` refers to different files ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - OK. :-) I interpreted "texts" in a different way, as a substitute/synonym for enumerated items of type "exercise"...

Comment: @Mico: Both interpretations are correct, in my point of view -- if it's the same file `\label` is sufficient, of course!

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you should set up a semi-customized enumerated list environment. One way to do this is with the facilities of the `enumitem` package. In the following example, a new enumerated list called "exlist" is defined and its formatting, labeling, and cross-referencing properties are specified. That way, items in the list can be cross-referenced using the standard `\label`-`\ref` mechanism.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for customized lists
\newlist{exlist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exlist]{leftmargin=*,itemindent=*,
         label = \textbullet\ \bfseries Exercise \arabic*.,
         ref   = Exercise \arabic*}
\begin{document}

\begin{exlist}
\item \label{ex:mult} $\phi(n)$ is multiplicative. 
\item By \ref{ex:mult} we have $\phi(n)=\prod_{p|n}(1-1/p)$.
\end{exlist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ...nice than mine! +1 (well, missing the Heinlein reference, but well...)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that you do not [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) the concept of label-reference in LaTeX  ☺.

You should have an automatic numbered thing to use the automatic referencing one --- otherwise it has no sense (if you fix the exercise to "1", you can use "1", no?). For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[exercise,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla
\begin{exercise}
\item \label{ex:simple} first exercise here 
\item \label{ex:complex} let's build on exercise~\ref{ex:simple}...
\end{exercise}

If you solved the exercises~\ref{ex:simple} and~\ref{ex:complex}, then \dots

\end{document}
```

(This is just to give an idea, probably the `theorems` environments are better for this, or `tcolorbox` to have fancy ones. Even this should be adjusted to remove the "dot" on the references, which surely can be done...).

This will compile to:

[image]

and if you add a intermediate item as `\item Hi, I though an intermediate here`:

[image]